# Test Code Coverage on VFP with SOQL query

Tags: visualforce, code-coverage, custom-controller

Have a custom object that we are using to document our refreshes to our sandboxes.  We are attempting to put this data onto a VFP so we can expose to non-licensed Salesforce workers using a Force.com Site.  Everything looks good with the exception I have been unable to get any code coverage on the customer controller for the page.  Can someone provide a little help of where I am off please?

Controller:

```
public class TableSandbox {  
    List<Sandbox__c> sandboxes;

        public List<Sandbox__c> getSandboxes() {       

                if(sandboxes == null) sandboxes = [select name, Location__c, Last_Refresh_Complete__c,
                Next_Refresh_Goal__c, Refresh_Frequency__c, Refresh_status__c, Project_Hold__c, Description__c, Notes__c   
                from sandbox__c limit 30]; 
                return sandboxes;
        }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest(seeAllData = false)
public class TableSandboxTestClass {
 public static testMethod void TestTableSandbox() 
  {
    Sandbox__c testBox = new Sandbox__c(Name = 'Test',Location__c = 'NA13',Refresh_Frequency__c='60', 
                                            Project_Hold__c=false, Description__c='Something',Notes__c='A Note');
    insert testBox;

    PageReference pageRef = Page.Sandboxes;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        Test.startTest();
    TableSandbox controller = new TableSandbox();
    Test.stopTest();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the look of it, it's simply a matter of you not calling the method that you want to test. By instantiating a `TableSandbox` the constructor will be run, but `getSandboxes()` isn't the constructor for this class.

If you call `controller.getSandboxes()` after instantiating your `TableSandox`, you should get your coverage. That said, coverage != tested, and you need to make assertions to test your code.

```
// @isTest defaults to seeAllData=false, so you don't need to specify that
@isTest
public class TableSandboxTestClass {
 public static testMethod void TestTableSandbox() 
  {
    Sandbox__c testBox = new Sandbox__c(Name = 'Test',Location__c = 'NA13',Refresh_Frequency__c='60', 
                                            Project_Hold__c=false, Description__c='Something',Notes__c='A Note');
    insert testBox;

    PageReference pageRef = Page.Sandboxes;
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

    Test.startTest();
    TableSandbox controller = new TableSandbox();
    List<Sandbox__c> results = controller.getSanboxes();
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertEquals(1, results.size());
    system.assertEquals(testBox.Name, results[0].Name);
    // And more assertions, as appropriate
  }
}
```